# Firestore listener not working after regaining internet connection on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, raspberry-pi, listener

I am running a Node.js application on my Raspberry Pi Zero W with the official Raspbian Lite OS connected to my home WiFi. The application registers a listener on a certain collection in the Firestore and listens for data changes. Everything works perfectly for days until the Raspberry loses internet connection. It reconnects pretty quickly, but after reconnecting, the listener does not receive any updates any more until I restart the application. No errors or other output comes from the application. I've also checked the logs from the Firestore libraries, but didn't find anything there too. The last log was about the last data change it received, and it was successful. The same application works just great after reconnecting to the internet when running on a Windows 10 PC. I am wondering whether this is a problem with the Raspberry or the Raspbian OS itself and how to check that. Are there any other logs that I could inspect? Maybe on the OS level? Or some other things to try to find what causes this issue?